# Android and using google account authtoken

Tags: android, web-services, accountmanager

I want to use the google authentication token for a google calendar webservice I have.
What are the alternatives sending the token from the android device to the webservice?.

Atm, Im getting my gmail account token from the accountmanager in my android device, but I'm not sure if this token is the correct one to use on my serverside to modify my google calendars (webservice with google API).

I would like some inputs on how to do these things, what's the proper method.

(The calendar logic needs to be on the webservice its a automation process running etc. etc. with timer/schedules and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any suggestions on how you should communicate between the client and the server, however the gmail account token is not the correct token to use if you want to integrate with the Google calendar.

The `authTokenType` you give to [getAuthToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) should be **oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar** if you need read/write access or **oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly** if read-only access is enough.

See also the documentation of the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

Comment: Thanks!, i have been a using different protocol. :):)